# How can I "hide" certain accounts from Global Search?

Tags: account, global-search

We have a number of accounts that are no longer interesting/relevant, but that we must keep in our org for a number of reasons.

Is there some kind of trick that we can use so that these records no longer show up in Global Search results? The distinguishing attribute is: a number of values for a custom multi-picklist field. For instance, all values of that field are {A, B, C, D, E}, but we no longer want accounts that have values of B or D to show up in Global Search results.

Comment: Have you considered [restriction rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_restriction_rule_create.htm&type=5)?

Comment: No I hadn't. I didn't even know they existed. Unfortunately "Restriction rules are available for custom objects, external objects, contracts, events, tasks, time sheets, and time sheet entries." so not available for accounts (I checked it, just in case, but indeed they are not there for accounts). Anyway, it would have been too restrictive: users must still be able to view the accounts (e.g. via lookup relations), and restriction rules would prevent that.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are asking for then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot restrict global search filters on account object, You might want to upvote for this [feature](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddFGUAZ/global-search-filters-per-object).

Answer (score 0):

Please see these beta features.

[Customize the User Search Experience in Search Manager](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_find_objects_fields.htm&type=5)

[Personalize Global Search for User Profiles with Objects to Always Search (Beta)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_ai_assign_result_objs.htm&type=5)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.